# I am trying to build my flutter release app bundle i error since i upgraded my flutter error is Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'

Tags: flutter

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    C:/Users/Trishna/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.5.30/5fd47535cc85f9e24996f939c2de6583991481b0/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.30.jar (version 1.5)
    C:/Users/Trishna/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.6.10/e1c380673654a089c4f0c9f83d0ddfdc1efdb498/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/Trishna/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.6.10/b8af3fe6f1ca88526914929add63cf5e7c5049af/kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/Trishna/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.6.10/c118700e3a33c8a0d9adc920e9dec0831171925/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.6.10.jar (version 1.6)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
ERROR:C:\Users\Trishna\AndroidStudioProjects\total_physical_user\build\flutter_inappwebview_quill\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\release\classes.jar: R8: Type com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: C:\Users\Trishna\AndroidStudioProjects\total_physical_user\build\flutter_inappwebview_quill\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\release\classes.jar:com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/BuildConfig.class, C:\Users\Trishna\AndroidStudioProjects\total_physical_user\build\flutter_inappwebview\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\release\classes.jar:com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/BuildConfig.class

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
> com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: C:\Users\Trishna\AndroidStudioProjects\total_physical_user\build\flutter_inappwebview_quill\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\release\classes.jar:com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/BuildConfig.class

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6m 35s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          398.2s

┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode.            │
│ To disable the shrinker, pass the `--no-shrink` flag to this command.      │
│ To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Try to run first `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get` and only then try again.

Answer (score 1):

In `app/build.gradle` change jdk7 to Java jdk8

before

```
 dependencies {
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

after

```
dependencies {
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: Thank you but i deleted the quill.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted quill library and all it's implementation. then it started to build. this happened after i updated to flutter 3.0.